# Ошибка php Undefined offset

Tags: php

Вот сам код

```php
    if($status[0]['status'] == 'close'){

        $access = "SELECT * FROM accesses WHERE id_login=$id_login AND access='teacher'";
        $access = mysqli_query($db, $access);// == true? true : false;

        $access = mysqli_num_rows($access) == 1? true : false;
        if($access && !$death)
            return true;
        else 
            return false;
    }
    else
        return true;

}
```

При переходе на сайт выходит вот такая вот ошибка

> Notice: Undefined offset: 0

Comment: Ну там еще и строка должна быть указана.

Comment: Ну с "0" только $status. Значит в $status нет элемента [0]

Answer (score 1):

Ну с `0` только `$status`. Значит в `$status` нет элемента `[0]`. 
Попробуйте `print_r($status);die;` на первой строке и увидите свой массив с его елементами, а там уже разберетесь с массивом. А если не получится, пишите в чат, чтобы разобраться.